# Repeatedly updating a page div in Rails from the Controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, progress-bar

I have a Rails 3 application that performs a long task of making several queries to a database to find documents. I want to show the user the progress of through the set of queries. I created a jquery function that employs the jquery.ui.progressbar. I want to update the progress bar dynamically as the document search controller loops through the search phrases. I need to know how to dynamically call the javascript to update the progressbar div in the document view. Please let me know how to call the javascript from the rails controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a remote function from your server unless it is responding to a request so would need to frequently send requests to your server from your application, check the progress of the search, and respond accordingly. Unless you're talking about more than 10 seconds I really would go for a spinner as it will be a lot easier and just as intuitive.

Edit:

*examples of how you may update your page in response to ajax polling*

```
#some_controller.rb

def check_download_progress
  #some_method
end

# javascript erb file. views/some_controller/check_download_progress.js.erb
# You can mix js and ruby and send it as a response to an ajax call; examples:

#check_download_progress.js.erb 

<%- if @some_value.present? -%>
  $('#progress_bar').addClass('<%= @some_value -%>');
<%- end -%>

#or simply call a function

my_remote_function(<%= @some_value -%>);
```

Comment: This task does not run in a form tag. Is there another way?

Comment: I didn't mention a form tag. You could for example add an id to a html element, detect its presence on document ready and start polling your server to check the status of the search.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding you answer. I have written a javascript function that polls and the polling works. I just need to find a way to pass the update value from the controller.

Comment: No need to apologize. I'll include a wee demo of how you can update your page.:)

Comment: I keep screwing something up. The progress bar to appear but I can't update. Run_assessment is the lengthy process. Get_progress has the updated progress. I call the get_progress for the Index action. How should I replace the value 50 with the variable?
Index.html.erb div:

<div id="progressbar"></div> 

Index.js:

$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 50 });  

Application.js:

$(function(){if ($("#progressbar").length > 0) {setTimeout(updateProgressbar, 5000);}
});

function updateProgressbar() {$.getScript("/assessments.js") setTimeout(updateProgressbar, 5000); }

Answer (score 0):

In your Rails action you could use RJS:

```
# Your AJAX action in controller.
def update_progress_bar
  render :update do |page|
    page.call 'java_script_method_name', 'param1', 'param2', etc.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to not use prototype. Does anyone know how to do the same thing using unobstructive javascript and jquery?